# Вывод запроса из бд SQLite в jTextArea

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc

У меня на форме есть `jList` в котором отображен список слов из ячейки word в БД SQLite. Я выбираю слово в нем и помещаю его в строчную переменную, которую затем помещаю в запрос на вывод ячейки `meaning` находящуюся в таблице `Wrd`. Для последующего вывода содержимого `meaning` в `jTextArea`. Вроде выглядит работоспособно, но почему-то результата нет, я не могу понять где я ошибся.

```
public class Frmt extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    Connection c=null;

    //Вывожу из бд в jList
    public void LoadList(){
        try {
            String qry = "Select * from Wrd;";
            PreparedStatement pst = c.prepareStatement(qry);
            ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
            DefaultListModel dlm = new DefaultListModel();
            while(rs.next()) {
                dlm.addElement(rs.getString("word"));
            }
            jList1.setModel(dlm);
            pst.close();
            rs.close();
        } catch(Exception e) {
    }
}

//Вывожу в jTextArea
public void getList() {
    try{
        String std = jList1.getSelectedValue();
        String qry = "Select meaning from Wrd where word = '"+std+"';";
        Statement st = c.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(qry);
        while(rs.next()) {
            jTextArea1.setText(rs.getString("meaning"));
        }
        st.close();
        rs.close();
    } catch(Exception e) {
    }
}  

public Frmt() {
    initComponents();
        try {
            Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
            c=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:Words.db");
            System.out.println("Connected");
        } catch(Exception e) {
        }
        LoadList();
        getList();
    }
```

`jList` заполняется нормально. В `getList` ошибки не происходит. Запрос (`qry`) принимает значение: `Select * from Wrd where word = 'null'`

Comment: `jList1` заполняется нормально? Происходят ли какие-либо ошибки (не оставляйте пустые `catch`напишите туда `System.out.println(e);` хотя бы)?

Comment: Также выведите чему равняется `qry` в `getList` и проверьте этот запрос.

Comment: @default locale jList1 выводится нормально без каких-либо ошибок. Попробовал написать System.out.println(rs.toString()); выдало во это: org.sqlite.jdbc4.JDBC4ResultSet@23a05c7a

Comment: `ResultSet` в строку не преобразовывается. Выведите запрос `System.out.println("Query: "+qry);` и исключение `System.out.println("Exception: "+e);`.

Comment: @default locale вывел запроc qry вот результат Select * from Wrd where word = 'null' ;  исключение молчит. Получается проблема в переменной std?

Comment: Да, в ней, она равна `null` потому что в списке ничего не выбрано

Comment: @default locale у меня были подозрения по поводу неё. Перелопатил уже все источники. И все равно не могу понять как организовать выбор элемента из jList

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> Select * from Wrd where word = 'null'
> ```

Это означает, что `jList1.getSelectedValue();` возвращает `null`. Происходит это из-за того, что в списке нет ни одного выбранного элемента.

Варианты решения:

1. Установить какое-либо из слов выбранным по-умолчанию, с помощью [`JList.setSelectedIndex`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html#setSelectedValue-java.lang.Object-boolean-). Например, первое по порядку:

   ```
   jList1.setModel(dlm);
   jList1.setSelectedIndex(0);
   ....
   ```
2. Подписаться на событие изменения выбранного значения в списке и перезаполнять `jTextArea1` когда пользователь выберет слово. Пример можете посмотреть в официальном уроке: «[How to Write a List Selection Listener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/listselectionlistener.html)»

P.S. Построение запроса путем слияния строк потенциально опасно. Почитайте: «Внедрение SQL кода» и научитесь передавать параметры в запросы (урок: «[Using Prepared Statements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)»).
P.P.S. Еще странно, что в вопросе получается `select *`, а не `select meaning` как написано.